# Kettle - Read multiple files from a folder

Tags: pentaho, readfile, kettle

I'm trying to read multiple XML files from a folder, to compile all the data they have (all of them have the same XML structure), and than save that data in a CSV file.

I already have a **'read-files' Transformation** with the steps: **Get File Names** and **Copy Rows to Result**, to get all the XML files. (it's working - I print a file with all the files names)

Then, I enter in a **'for-each-file' Job** which has a **Transformation** with the **Get Rows from Result Step**, and then another Job to process those files.

I think I'm loosing information from the **'read-files' Transformation** to the **Transformation in the 'for-each-file' Job** which Get all the rows. (I print another file with all the files names, but it is empty)

Can you tell me if I'm thinking in the right way? I have to set some variables, or some option that is disabled? Thanks.

Comment: Basically you have one root job englobing two lower level jobs, right? In the root job, you can use a step "add filenames to result" before the first lower level job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of "How to process a Kettle transformation once per filename"
http://www.timbert.net/doku.php?id=techie:kettle:jobs:processtransonceperfile

Comment: I had already seen that example, and that really resolved my problem.